# Writing a custom converter to handle non-html tags

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor5

When CKEditor5 sees bad HTML like this:

```
  @foreach ($data as $datum)
    <div>
      <span>{{ $datum }}</span>
    </div>
  @endforeach
```

It will wrap the tags in 'p' so it turns out looking like this:

```
<p>
    @foreach ($data as $datum)
</p>
<div>
    <span>{{ $datum }}</span>
</div>
<p>
    @endforeach
</p>
```

I believe it should be possible to prevent that from happening with a custom converter plugin or even in the config by messing with the model writer. Or do I need to hack it during the upcasting stage, which I'd be willing to do. What should I look at to start with this? Thanks.

I think I would start by getting the data model to not see it as "paragraph".

If it's not possible, how do I change the paragraph to something else? Using a different tag would work for me.

I also need it to work in tables as well. This just gets deleted:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                foo
            </td>
        </tr>
  @foreach ($data as $datum)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $datum }}
            </td>
        </tr>
  @endforeach
        <tr>
            <td>
                bar
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I make this not be deleted?

[image]

Comment: If you don't want it to get wrapped in `<p>` then what should happen to the text? Wrap it in `<pre>` tag?  `@foreach ($data as $datum)` is a server side code, Blade Template maybe?. It has no meaning in webbrowsers. CKEditor 5 is client side library so it'll always treat it as a some text and wrap it in <p> tag. May be I am not getting your use case.

Comment: @onkar ruikar I have my own DSL running in client side js that will interpret this code at runtime. For the CKeditor model it's fine to wrap it in anything, div pre or code or even a new tag that's a version of code that works at the block level maybe? Just when it downcasts I would like it to unwrap. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to make sense you would first translate your dsl into html before feeding it to the ckeditor.

Comment: @html_programmer maybe i'm being dumb but isn't that what up and downcasting is? It seems better to take advantage of ckeditor's existing ability to do that than to write a new thing no?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. But it looks like you're feeding tags to the ckeditor that it doesn't understand. In order to resolve, they wrap it in `<p></p>` tags rather than letting it crash. Makes sense to me... I don't really understand why feeding tags to ckeditor that it doesn't understand. Seems to make sense to compile custom template syntax first. But maybe I'm missing something in your question.

Comment: @html_programmer It's in CKEditor in the uncompiled state because I want users to be able to edit the DSL in CKEditor like that. Wrapping it in `<p>` is understandable but i'd prefer `pre` and someway to unwrap before it goes back to source view.

Comment: @Harry Personally I would discuss this through Github with the maintainers of the project by logging an issue if this feature isn't described in the api. Sorry I could not be of further help.

Comment: @Harry please can you share the example code that you have tried so far.